# Beginner SharePoint / Access Web Database question

Tags: database, sharepoint, ms-access

I'm fairly new to SharePoint and Access. I've started building a basic SharePoint for my company to use and I have two different Access web databases up on it. One for projects and one for managing contacts.

I know SharePoint web parts can access SharePoint lists, but is there a way I can have SharePoint access a web database on the site? I'm sure I can, I just am unsure of how to do it.

I'm sorry if its a silly question but, like I said, this is all new to me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

follow the links provided below they will guide what all you can do

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/introduction-to-integrating-data-between-access-and-a-sharepoint-site-HA010131463.aspx

http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=189